# How to set up my belongs_to and has_many reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ExpenseType object that I have created with the following migration:

```
class CreateExpenseTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :expense_types do |t|
      t.column :name, :string, :null => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

I can see the table name is the pluralised expense_types.  My question is, how do I reference this type in a belongs_to relationship?

Is it:

```
belongs_to :expensetype
```

or is it

```
   belongs_to :expense_type
```

I do not seem able to set it up correctly.

Also, how would I reference the object if it was contained in an expense object like this:

```
class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :expense_type
end
```

would it be:

```
expense.expense_type
```

or

```
expense.expensetype
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct with:

```
# app/models/expense.rb
class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :expense_type
end
```

You can also setup `ExpenseType` as follows:

```
# app/models/expense_type.rb
class ExpenseType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :expenses
end
```

Also, if `expense` is an instance of `Expense`, you can access the `expense_type` as:

```
expense.expense_type
```

### For more information

see **[ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001835)**